# Shortest way to modify some element in list when condition is matched C#

Tags: c#, list, linq

Ex. I want to modify the element in list that "id" is matched. I do like this.

```
for(int i=0;i<list.Count;i++){
    if(list[i].id==id){
        list[i].data = newData;
        break;
    }
}
```

Is there any shorter way to do?

Answer (score 0):

[Convert your list to dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277(v=vs.110).aspx) and use id as a key:

```
var dictionary = list.ToDictionary(o => o.id);
//...
dictionary[id].data = newData;
```

Comment: What happens when Id are multiple, possible in a List but not in a dictionary, will fail for duplicate records

Comment: @MrinalKamboj it's out of this question. I don't know type of id and other data.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj isn't id expected to be unique?

Comment: @yolosora not necessary, `List<T>` can easily contain duplication, no way to avoid it

Answer (score 0):

```
list = list.Select(x =>
{
      if(x.id == id)
      {
           x.data = newdata;
           break;
      }
      return x;
}
```